# The eigenvalue of $A^TA$

Tags: matrices

If $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of matrix $A$,what is the eigenvalue of $A^TA$?I have no clue about it. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: real matrix...complex matrix...? Not that it matters, but it makes the question more neatly posted.

Comment: Do you mean $\lambda$ is *one* eigenvalue or the only eigenvalue? In general, the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$ have little to do with the eigenvalues of $A$. See [singular values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: @TedShifrin what about $\lambda_{\mbox{max}}A^TA$ and $\lambda_{\mbox{max}}(A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good exercise for you is to prove, in general, that 
$$\lambda_{\text{max}}(A)\le \max_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|=\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(A^\top A)}.$$

Comment: Is $\frac{(\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{\mbox{min}}(A+A^T))^2}{\lambda_{\mbox(max)}A^TA}<1$ if A is positive definite

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you won't be able to say much about them.

However, if $A$ is for instance real symmetric, it is diagonalizable with real eigenvalues, meaning there is an orthogonal matrix B (that is with $B^{-1}=B^T$) and a diagonal matrix D such that:
$$A = B D B^T$$
$$A^TA = (B D B^T)^T B D B^T = B D^T B^T B D B^T = BD^2B^T$$
In other words, the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$.